# How to check if the user input is the correct answer or not?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an online application for children that picks a random image from a database using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var random_images_array = ['apple.gif', 'book.gif',...]

function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) 
{
path = path || 'images/';
var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
var img = imgAr[ num ];
var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
document.write(imgStr); document.close();
}
</script>
```

My question is how can I tell the computer whether the input from the user is the correct answer or not?
For example if the programme is showing the apple image, the user should type “apple” and the system should return a “correct” message.
p.s. the name of the images represent the content of that image.

Comment: You need more than just an array of images; you need an *associative array*, an array that associates each image with a word.  Associative arrays are very easy to do in Javascript.  For more general information about how to do them, see http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html

Comment: My question is actually does the programme after executing this code, know which image has been selected? So we can check the input from the user against this.

Comment: The program could if you make `num` a global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to check the user input against the name of the image, first, make `num` a global variable so you can access it in any function. Then, write a function to check the user input against the item in `random_images_array` at the index `num` - the extension. Here is the final code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var random_images_array = ['apple.gif', 'book.gif',...]
var num = 0;

function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) 
{
    path = path || 'images/';
    num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
    var img = imgAr[num];
    var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
    document.write(imgStr); document.close();
}

function checkUserInput() {
var userInput = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
var stringToCheckAgainst = random_image_array[num].split('.');
//this splits the item at the array index into an array, like so. If the item is "apple.gif", the array reads ["apple", "gif"]
if (userInput == stringToCheckAgainst[0]) {
    //user has inputted the correct string
    window.alert("user gave correct response!");
} else {
    //user has inputted an incorrect string
    window.alert("user gave incorrect response!");
}
}
</script>
<input type="text" placeholder="placeholder text goes here" id="textInput" />
<button type="button" onclick="checkUserInput();">Check your answer!</button>
```

Comment: How should I connect my input text to this code?

Comment: I will edit the answer to include a text input and a way to get the input value

Comment: this code is not displaying anything...

Comment: Try with the alerts I just added

Comment: still is not displaying any responce, shouldnt if (userInput == stringToCheckAgainst[num]), instead of if (userInput == stringToCheckAgainst[0])

Comment: no, the `num` is the index of the image in your image array. `0` is the index of anything before the `.` in the string which is represented by `random_image_array[num]`

Comment: i have put the code in my <head>, should i put it in my body?

Comment: the `<script>...</script>` needs to be in the head, the `<input />` and `<button>...</button>` should be in the body

Comment: thanks for that, but when i press the button it does not do anything!